# Sync all libraries in a site with Office 365

Tags: sharepoint, office365

I have a home page and put some icons to link to 8 different libraries. I can sync all documents from each library to my computer. However, if there are more than 20 libraries, I would like to have any button or function to sync all libraries from a site to my computer. Please help me to address these problems as below:

1. Is that impossible to sync all libraries with only 1 click from a site?
2. If Yes, how about the permission for any special users if they has been granted to view some libraries?
3. If No, is there any solution to solve that issue?

---

[image: 1]